# Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed always returns false

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am trying to access the UserInformation in a Windows Store App.

Specifically, I would like to get the `DisplayName`.

I have updated the app manifest file to include Enterprise Authentication & even tried adding Account Picture Provider in the hope that this would help.

Unfortunately, `NameAccessAllowed` always returns false, so `GetDisplayNameAsync()` returns an empty string.

Is there some other privilege I need to enable in the manifest perhaps?

Update:

I forgot to mention that I have already tried the User domain name sample.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/User-domain-name-sample-85ce3e49

Comment: Checkout this link I am quite sure that there are numerous other examples on the web http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2

Comment: Here is a better link Straight from Microsoft http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Account-picture-name-sample-912baff1#content

Comment: Yeah the first one is not about getting UserInformation, only ApplicationData and local settings etc.

Comment: I posted a link in the answer ...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if the user does not have a Microsoft Account setup 
then based on Microsoft's Site

Getting the DisplayName will return Empty String 
[DisplayName and GetDisplayNameAsync()](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Account-picture-name-sample-912baff1#content)

Comment: This is the problem yes, but I do not understand why. I go into PC settings and it has an Option to switch to a local account. so looks like I already have a Microsoft account setup. certainly did this when installing. Odd.

Comment: awesome I am glad I was able to finally locate the proper URL to use for that problem / Issue that you were experiencing ..

Answer (score 2):

Turning on "Let apps access my name, picture and other account info" option in "PC Settings -> Privacy" Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows security settings you have to allow apps to obtain this information. So NameAccessAllowed will return true.